# How to increase i to next call?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Every celltest() function run, I want to increase i value

```
function cell_test () {
   var i=8 ;
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
   var source = ss.getRange ("A!C1");
   var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("B");
   var destRange = destSheet.getRange(i,2);
   source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});


}
```

This code works as below...

When it calls cell_test (), it copy value from A!C1 and paste it at B sheet (8.2) cell position(i=8).

Next time call, I want to increase i value +1 and paste it to (9.2) cell position (i=9).

How to increase i values every cell_test ()?

Please help me out.
Thank you

Comment: What is "i"?  Always 8 when you open the spreadsheet?  The first empty row of B?  And how is cell_test run, from menu, custom formula, onEdit?

Comment: the target cell is B sheet (8.2) which i want to paste. so i give i value to 8.Then i will paste value to B sheet (9.2).

Comment: You haven't answered my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Storing and Incrementing a variable in the Properties Service

Try this:

```
function initI() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('i',8);
  return Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('i'));
}

function incrI() {
  var ps=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var i=Number(ps.getProperty('i'));
  ps.setProperty('i',i+1);
}

function getI() {
  var ps=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var pObj=ps.getProperties(); 
  if(pObj.hasOwnProperty('i')) {
     var i=Number(ps.getProperty('i'));
    return i;
  }else{
    return initI();
  }
}

function cell_test() {
  var i=getI();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange ("A!C1");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("B");
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(i,2);
  source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  incrI();
}
```

- [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

> This is handy because all you have to do is add var `i=getI();` at the beginning of any test function and at `incrI();` at the end of your test function and the rest is taken care of.  If your I is not defined in the property service getI() will take care of that for you.  If you wish to start all over you can just run initI() and that will set it to the default value which is currently 8. If you wish to change the default value then just change the 8 in initI() and your done.  You can completely delete the PropertiesService value for in in the Files/Project Properties/Script Properties dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `i` a function parameter and call the function from a for loop:

```
function main() {
  var startRow = 8;
  var endRow = 10;

  for(var i=startRow; i<=endRow; i++) {
    cell_test(i);
  }
}

function cell_test(i) {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
   var source = ss.getRange ("A!C1");
   var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("B");
   var destRange = destSheet.getRange(i,2);
   source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

This will copy the content of cell `A!C1` to cell `B!B8`, `B!B9` and `B!B10`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i needs to be reset or how cell_test is run but this will increment i each time the function is run.

```
function cell_test() {
  try {
    // Increment i
    var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    var i = props.getProperty("Test");
    if( i === null ) {
      i = 8;
    }
    else {
      i++;
    }
    props.setProperty("Test", i);
    // Put your code here
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
    var source = ss.getRange ("A!C1");
    var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("B");
    var destRange = destSheet.getRange(i,2);
    source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```